# Python constructor "self = "

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I was writing a class and at some point I decided that it would be nice to have a possibility to create an instance of the class using other instance of this same class. So basically the class would look like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if type(b) == Test:
            self = a / b
        else:
            self.a = a
            self.b = b

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return Test(other * self.b, self.a)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.a = }, {self.b = }"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hf = Test(1, 2)
    print(hf)  # self.a = 1, self.b = 2
    print(Test(1, hf))  # AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'
    print(1 / Test(1, hf))  # AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'b'
```

However, when i tried to do it, I got the AttributeError (*AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'*). Interestingly enough, the code `print(1/Test(1, hf))` gives the same attribute error about attribute *b* while going into the *rtruediv* func, so the object `Test(1, hf)` has methods that I defined. Why does that happen? Is something wrong with "self = ..."?

Comment: `self = ...` is a no-op. It just repoints the name "self" in the method scope to some object. No change to the actual object takes place

Comment: Side note: As pointed out in one of the answers, you shouldn't compare `type(...)` values for equality and should instead use `isinstance(b, Test)`, so that if someone (for instance, you six months in the future) subclasses `Test` at some point, then it'll still work via [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: `__init__` is just an initializer. It initializes an existing object. You cannot replace this object with other objects. If you want to create objects in different ways according to some conditions, it may be appropriate to define a suitable `__new__` method here.

Comment: @rdas Thanks, I see it now. Is there any way to fix it so that _self =_ would change the actual object? Also I don't understand why you've written it as a comment and not as an answer:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `self` is just an ordinary variable like any other.

```
if type(b) == Test:
    self = a / b
else:
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

In the `if` branch, we reassign a local variable, but it doesn't change the instance being constructed. It just makes a new instance, that will be discarded in a moment. The *actual* instance being constructed (the original value of `self`) is still there and remains in an uninitialized state (i.e. doesn't have `a` and `b` like it should).

I think your goal here is well-intentioned, though it will likely confuse Python programmers as it's not incredibly idiomatic. My recommendation is to simply set `self.a` and `self.b` in the constructor in all cases, as it's a more intuitive code design for the average Python coder.

*However,* what you want can be done. In Python, when you call `Test(a, b)`, some complicated internal things happen.

1. First, we invoke `__call__` on the metaclass of `Test`. In your example, the metaclass of `Test` isn't specified, so it defaults to [`type`], the built-in metaclass.
2. The default behavior of `type.__call__` is to invoke the class method `__new__` on your class (`__new__` is implicitly a class method, even if you don't ask it to be, so you don't need the `@classmethod` decorator). Your class doesn't currently define `__new__`, so we inherit the default one from `object`.
3. `object.__new__` actually creates the new object. This is written in low-level C and can't be replicated in Python. It truly is primitive.
4. Finally, `object.__new__` calls `Test.__init__` on the newly-constructed object and then returns the new object.

Aside from (3), which is truly a C-level primitive, we can easily inject into any part of this. We could write a metaclass and redefine `__call__`, but that's overkill for what we're doing. We're going to hook into (2) and define `__new__`. So rather than your `__init__`, consider

```
class Test:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if type(b) == Test:
            return a / b
        else:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            obj.a = a
            obj.b = b
            return obj
```

In `__init__`, we're given the object to construct, and our only option is to construct *that* object (or throw an exception if we can't). But `__new__` is lower-level. In `__new__`, it's *our* choice whether and how to create a new object. In the case where we're given two numbers, we delegate to the default `__new__` on `object` (creating a new object, using the primitive C-level code discussed above), and then we initialize its instance variables. But in the case where `b` is a `Test`, we do something different and short-circuit the process entirely, calling a different method instead.

Again, I don't necessarily think this is super idiomatic Python code, but it is possible to do what you want.